# change style invalid && touched

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

I'm trying to change an `i` tag style when another field is `touched` and `invalid` as follow but nothing really changes with `i` tag, only the `input` tag changes.

```css
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid
{
    border-color: red;
}

input.ng-valid
{
    border-color: green ;
}

.green-icon
{
    color:green;
}
.red-icon
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <i class="fas fa-user circle"  [class.green-icon]="CardOwnerName.valid" [class.red-icon]="CardOwnerName.invalid && CardOwnerName.touched"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input #CardOwnerName formControlName="CardOwnerName" name="CardOwnerName" class="form-control" placeholder="Card Owner Name" required>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something with my Angular version. Perhaps something was deprecated?

Comment: Are you using template driven form or reactive form

Comment: I'm using reactive form

Comment: Change `CardOwnerName.valid` to `myForm.controls.CardOwnerName.valid`. Or rename the template alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error fixed by `ChangeDetectionRef`.

```js
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor( private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.cdref.detectChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ref to the element in the template, and instead access the form object:

```
<input formControlName="CardOwnerName" name="CardOwnerName" class="form-control" placeholder="Card Owner Name" required>
```

```
get CardOwnerName() {
    return this./* form group name here */.get('CardOwnerName');
}
```

Comment: is this will work for  the `i` tag? I 'm familiar with this approach but would like to change another tag's style according to `CardOwnerName` validations.

Comment: Yes, with those changes, the rest of the template should work as is. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <i class="fas fa-user circle" [ngClass]="{'red-icon': form.get('CardOwnerName').invalid, 'green-icon': form.get('CardOwnerName').valid }"  ></i>
```

or,

```
<i class="fas fa-user circle" [ngClass]="(form.get('CardOwnerName').valid)?'green-icon':'red-icon'"  ></i>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7po4oe?embed=1&file=src/app/personal/personal.component.html)**

Comment: the first option works. almost. It works as expected but console has error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'green-icon: true'. Current value: 'green-icon: false'.` it happens when page loads

Comment: Can you check the demo I added, Something else is causing this issue, you can also share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: the demo looks good. But it works for me as expected as well. the problem is when opening the developer tools in Chrome. I suddenly see that there are error, although it works in client

Comment: Ya, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError can occur for various reasons. Can you show your complete code in stackbiltz. As you can see in the demo I shared, it is not happening in my case.

Comment: yes. I'll try to do that ASAP..it's my first time uploading to stackblitz

Comment: can a `git` project help? I cannot upload a `stackblitz` project for some reason. opened a bug report for that .  [my git project](https://github.com/eliavyaniv/angular-test-git/)